# Which function returns "nvmlDevice_t" type variable in cuda/nvml library?

Tags: c++, cuda, nvidia, return-type, nvml

I am working with gpu's and want to get the serial numbers of the gpu's.In NVIDIA Management Library there is a function that I can use. The function prototype is. 
`nvmlReturn_t nvmlDeviceGetSerial ( nvmlDevice_t device, char* serial, unsigned int  length );`
The first parameter is "nvmlDevice_t device".I have searched a lot but does not find any function which returns this type.So how can I get this?

Comment: "In each case the device is identified with an nvmlDevice_t handle. This handle is obtained by calling one of nvmlDeviceGetHandleByIndex(), nvmlDeviceGetHandleBySerial(), nvmlDeviceGetHandleByPciBusId(). or nvmlDeviceGetHandleByUUID()."

Comment: Thanks.You helped me a lot.

Comment: I will add that as an answer if you would like to accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quoting from the [documentation](https://docs.nvidia.com/deploy/nvml-api/group__nvmlDeviceQueries.html) preamble:

> This chapter describes that queries that NVML can perform against each
>   device. In each case the device is identified with an nvmlDevice_t
>   handle. This handle is obtained by calling one of
>   [nvmlDeviceGetHandleByIndex()](https://docs.nvidia.com/deploy/nvml-api/group__nvmlDeviceQueries.html#group__nvmlDeviceQueries_1g52677ecb45f937c5005124608780a3f4), [nvmlDeviceGetHandleBySerial()](https://docs.nvidia.com/deploy/nvml-api/group__nvmlDeviceQueries.html#group__nvmlDeviceQueries_1g3e4b72c1aef967266930ba0388a76628),
>   [nvmlDeviceGetHandleByPciBusId()](https://docs.nvidia.com/deploy/nvml-api/group__nvmlDeviceQueries.html#group__nvmlDeviceQueries_1g3e4b72c1aef967266930ba0388a76628). or [nvmlDeviceGetHandleByUUID()](https://docs.nvidia.com/deploy/nvml-api/group__nvmlDeviceQueries.html#group__nvmlDeviceQueries_1g72710fb20f30f0c2725ce31579832654).

With that, it should be fairly self-explanatory to get the handle you require.